# How to run PHP scripts on server without updating server's files

Tags: php, database, deployment, server, remote-debugging

I need to run PHP scripts on server without having to update files it stores - perform testing on real server before deployment. Server has access to database which is inaccessible from outside. For this reason I can't run my scripts locally, I need to run them within server's environment, but I don't want to update files stored on server. Is there any way to do so? Is there a tool for remote PHP debugging?

Comment: Why you cannot just back up DB and import it into your localhost?

Comment: That is sure an option, but I would prefer to consider this as a last resort since it will require me to install DBMS and to keep track of server's DB data model changes. What I was looking for is a ready-to-use solution for remote PHP debugging which will allow me to run scripts in isolated environment on server(maybe an extension to Apache web server or something).

Comment: Development and testing against a copy (simulated or real) of the production database is more common. Working against the live production database is not a good idea. Tools like vagrant make it much simpler nowadays to run an entire system locally.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Thanks for your comment) I will probably stick to virtualization-based solution since everybody here were talking me out of my original approach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution - XDebug for PHP. However as was mentioned in comments, testing against copy of DB and using virtualization is a more common approach, which I personally will probably stick to.
For those who are still determined to go the "hard" way, here is a link to HOWTO on XDebug installation for PHP on Ubuntu - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=525257.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve this thing

1. You can export database from live server and import it to your local server for testing and debugging purpose.
2. You can Upload code into a separate folder or subdomain on server to connect with database and test with live server configurations. Once you are satisfied replace live files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer) The whole thing is about testing changes without having to perform a deployment each time change has been made, thus second suggestion won't work for me. The first approach is similar to what was proposed at comments to initial post, please see my comments.

Comment: Are you using SVN/GIT or any other repository system?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Git and I have established push-to-deploy.